# Attachment.Name when retrieving email attachments is null

Tags: pdf, attachment, system.net.mail, openpop

I'm using openpop to retrieve and process emails, In processing the mails, I'm checking for attachments and saving them to a specific folder.  This works fine for csv files but for some reason for pdfs "att.Name" is returning null and won't save.

```
AttachmentCollection attachments = mailItem.Attachments;
foreach (Attachment att in attachments)
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(conf.AttachmentSaveTo + att.Name,   FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        att.ContentStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the raw message, it's possible that the MIME headers for your pdf attachments do not specify a file name.

If you look at the raw message source, check to see if your pdf attachments have a `Content-Disposition` header and make sure that they have a `filename` parameter.

If not, does the `Content-Type` header have a `name` parameter?

If at least 1 of those 2 parameters is present, perhaps you have discovered a bug in OpenPOP. If that's the case, I would suggest using my [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) library instead.